# An unpublished note by Spencer Bloch and Kazuya Kato

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, log-geometry

I am looking for an unpublished note by Spencer Bloch and Kazuya Kato, p-divisible groups and Dieudonné crystals. This note is always cited as

Spencer Bloch and Kazuya Kato, p-divisible groups and Dieudonné crystals, unpublished.
http://staff.science.uva.nl/˜bmoonen/pDivDieudCryst.pdf, 46 pp.

However the link above is no more available. I know maybe the best way is to email the authors directly but I still want to have a try here.

About my background

I am interested in this note because it seems that Kato and Bloch were able to prove a logarithmic Dieudonne theory of p-divisible groups over some semi-stable bases. So any other references on this topic are also appreciated.

Comment: https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~ty245/camonly/Kato_pDivDieudCryst.pdf

Comment: @JoeBerner Thank you Joe, it really helps a lot.

Comment: both links no longer work, here is an alternative: https://mathoverflow.net/a/362082/11260