# An unpublished note by Bloch-Kato on p-divisible groups and Dieudonné crystals

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, log-geometry

I wonder if anyone could find the following unpublished paper of Bloch-Kato:

Spencer Bloch and Kazuya Kato, $p$-divisible groups and Dieudonné crystals, unpublished.

A similar question is here while both links in the question are failed right now.

[An unpublished note by Spencer Bloch and Kazuya Kato](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/272044/an-unpublished-note-by-spencer-bloch-and-kazuya-kato)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The unpublished note was no longer on the Web (also [archive.org](https://archive.org) did not have it cached). I asked professor Moonen for a copy to share with you, here it is: [p-divisible groups and Dieudonné crystals](https://www.ilorentz.org/beenakker/MO/pDivDieudCryst.pdf) by Bloch and Kato.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Carlo!